# Finding $k$ when $f(x)=kx^{-(k+1)}$.

Tags: integration, statistics, probability-distributions

I am trying to do the following question:

[image]

How do I find the constant k? Do I use $\int_{1}^{\infty}f(x)dx = 1$? If so, then the integral is just equal to $1$...

Comment: But you must show it!

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Show what?

Comment: Have you even calculated the integral? It is not equal to 1, it is equal to a value, dependent on k

Comment: That the result is equal to one.

Comment: Yeah, it is equal to 1, if you find values for k so that the resulting expression, which is $1 - \frac{1}{\infty^{k}}$, is equal to $1$

Comment: $k$ here is not as such a normalising constant whose value can be found from $\int_1^\infty f(x)\,dx=1$, but rather a parameter (it is a Pareto distribution). Indeed, as shown below, any positive value of $k$ is valid for $f$ to be a pdf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are supposed to use that the integral is equal to $1$, so 
$$\int_1^\infty kx^{-(k+1)}dx=1\\\left.\frac k{-(k)}x^{-k}\right|_1^\infty=1\\
\frac {k}{k}=1$$
and I find  any $k \gt 0$ is a solution because you need the integral to converge.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply. So I can choose any such positive $k$ for this function?

Comment: That is correct, and what I said at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Yes for the integral to exist as x goes to $\infty$ , k  shall be bigger than  0   $$\int_1^\infty f(x) \, dx = -\frac{1}{x^k}+1$$ 
you can clearly see if k is negative or zero the integral diverges